# Close the dialogue during the process (Android, java)

Tags: android

In the application there is a dialog box with a button. When I click the button - begins execution of the process. Processing time is about 30 seconds. And while it will fail the dialog box isn't close. But I need to window closed immediately after pressing the button. Code:

```
private void Dialog1() {
    final Dialog typeDialog = new Dialog(myContext);
    typeDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    typeDialog.setContentView(R.layout.type_dialog);
    typeDialog.show();
        TextView chooseText = (TextView) typeDialog.findViewById(R.id.typeText);
    chooseText.setText("Text");
    Button dialogButton = (Button) typeDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButton);
        dialogButton.setText("OK");

    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            start();
            typeDialog.dismiss();
             }
    });
```

I need to execute typeDialog.dismiss() at the same time with starting start().

Here is a solution, based on using separate threads:

```
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                typeDialog.dismiss();
                new newThread();
                 }


class newThread implements Runnable {
    Thread thread;
    playThread() {
        thread = new Thread(this, "New Thread");            
        thread.start();                                     
    }
    public void run() {
        start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `typeDialog.dismiss()` first?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just close the dialog first and then call the start method,
you could also use a progress dialog to show a loading spinner on the screen for those 30 seconds when you call the start() method.

dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

```
    public void onClick(View view){

        typeDialog.dismiss();
        start();
        }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Process start() is starting, but dialog closes only when start() is finished.

Answer (score 0):

his is sample:

Do as follows;

```
//Declare it global
AlertDialog alert;
```

**Step 1:**

```
alert = typeDialog.create();
alert.show();
```

**Step 2:**
Inside of button onclick

```
if (alert != null) {
            alert.cancel();
        }
```

I write this for some other purpose and for `AlertDialog.Builder`. Please try. I am not 100% sure it will work

Comment: Something wrong with this code - there is a problem with connection between alert and typeDialog, but thank you, I'll try to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Another one piece of code Try this:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder typeDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater
                        .from(MainActivity.this);
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.type_dialog, null);
                typeDialog.setView(v);
                alert = typeDialog.create();
                alert.show();
                Button dialogButton = (Button) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.dialogButton);
                dialogButton.setText("OOk");
                TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.typeText);
                tv.setText("Helllllllo");
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        alert.cancel();
 start();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: The same situation - until the process is completed, dialog box doesn't close. May be there is another solution: to use separates threads for Dialog1() and start().

Comment: Try to call  alert.cancel(); before your  start(); method.